# ant.design table with sticky header and scrollbar shrinks column width to the contents' size rendering titles of empty columns unreadable

Tags: antd

How should the CSS be adapted without setting fix column widths so that all columns are at least as wide as the titles? The only change was the setting of `sticky` on the table.

On this screenshot only 7 out of 17 column titles are readably visible:

[image: On this screenshot only 7 out of 17 column titles are readably visible]

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the width of the regular cells must be specified so that they're at least as wide as the related headers.
This css makes it look acceptable, but still too wide for certain columns:

```css
.projektTable th {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.projektTable td {
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-width: 180px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would import an `overrides.css` file with the following:

```css
th.ant-table-cell {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Now the headers will be displayed in a row (unwrapped), but still truncated ie. the header cell widths is aligned with the content of the cells.